# gem install error--Ruby version >=1.9.3 required

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have been attempting to install the httparty gem, but the install fails with:

```
Error installing httparty:
httparty requires Ruby version >=1.9.3
```

My ruby version, from running ruby -v, is 1.9.3p448

Running gem env yields:

```
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.7
RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3
INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: .../ruby 1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby
RUBY EXECUTABLE: .../ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin
GEM PATHS:
   .../gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448
   .../ruby-1.8.3-p448@global
```

Any ideas why this is failing & what i can to to fix it, short of manually editing the gem to remove the 1.9.3 requirement?

Comment: sounds like a bug to me, I'd manually edit it then submit a pull request :)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to me like it isn't using Ruby 1.9.3 as that is exactly what the error says. I had the same error message today when pushing to Heroku:

```
   Installing httparty (0.12.0)
   Gem::InstallError: httparty requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
   An error occurred while installing httparty (0.12.0), and Bundler cannot
   continue.
   Make sure that `gem install httparty -v '0.12.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I just added

```
ruby '1.9.3'
```

to the top of my Gemfile like so:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '3.0.20'
```

and all is well.